# Firebase searching by character

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in my firebase app and I am still till now didn't know how to search in Firebase by character, I have already used an query and I have got a good result but its not usable, here's my database I want to search in:

[image]

And here's my method that I use it but it get the "Username" if I enter full name only so if I write "m" nothing show:

```
mMainSearcher.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            Query Q = mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username").equalTo(newText);

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Friends, Search.SearchViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter22 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Friends, Search.SearchViewHolder>(
                    Getting_Friends.class, R.layout.my_friends_card, Search.SearchViewHolder.class, Q) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final Search.SearchViewHolder viewHolder, final Getting_Friends model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                    viewHolder.setProfile(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfile());

                }
            };
            mFriendsRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter22);
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Here's what I got when I enter fully name:

[image]

And here's what I got when I write "M" or "m":

[image]

So I only need >> When I write "m" automatically all users name start with "m" must be shown like mike.

Comment: I also want to search by char, i'm also using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Given solution didn't work for me, can you plz help me! How did you achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304619/not-able-to-implement-the-filter-in-searchview-searchview-firebaserecyclerada here's my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Query Q = mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username").startAt(newText).endAt("~");
```

Comment: @7uthaifah, I am tryign the same solution, but my new list goes below previous list, do you do any kind of cleanup for recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using:

```
Query Q = mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username").equalTo(newText);
```

The [`equalsTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#equalTo(java.lang.String)) creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with the given value.

You should use the method [`startAt`](http://Create%20a%20query%20constrained%20to%20only%20return%20child%20nodes%20with%20a%20value%20greater%20than%20or%20equal%20to%20the%20given%20value,%20using%20the%20given%20orderBy%20directive%20or%20priority%20as%20default.) which creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

Comment: I have already used this method >> Query Q = mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username").startAt(newText); but it also didn't show anything