# Firebase Recycler Adapter with searchview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hi I've been implementing a search feature however I'm getting E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error only whenever I Have my code as shown below. However whenever I remove the query my recyclerview comes back to normal? I'm not sure how to solve this. I appreciate your time and help

```
mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Query search = mDataRef.orderByChild("Societies").startAt(newText).endAt("~");
            final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<society, PostViewHolderSoc> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<society, PostViewHolderSoc>(
                    society.class, R.layout.society_row, PostViewHolderSoc.class, search )
            {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolderSoc viewHolder, final society model, final int position)
                {
                    final String society_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent viewSingleSociety = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SocietyDetail.class);
                            viewSingleSociety.putExtra("society_id", society_key);
                            startActivity(viewSingleSociety);
                        }
                    });
                    viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.setType(model.getType());
                }
            };

         mSocietyList.setAdapter(adapter);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you Have Large Data to search in , So you need to search over Firebase ?

Comment: Yeah basically, I've seen this user have luck by doing it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536273/firebase-searching-by-character however I can't seem to get mine working.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a local search using `Filterable` then check this out I have created custom FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that support the Filterable feature.

[Custom Filterable FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/67c42f8f32efaa2fadb682bc980e9280)