# not able to implement the filter in SearchView. (SearchView+ FirebaseRecyclerAdapter)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview, android-recyclerview

I am using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter of Firebase-UI. I'm not able to implement the filter in SearchView.

**My database:**

[image]

**My Question:**

**How to search in FirebaseDatabase by character using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter ?**
(I want to search by username)

**My Code:** I used this method for search, what's wrong in my code?

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            Query Q = mAllUsersDatabaseRef.child("User").orderByChild("username").startAt(newText).endAt("~");

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, SearchFeedFragment.AllRegisterUserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, SearchFeedFragment.AllRegisterUserViewHolder>(
                    User.class, R.layout.row_search_all_users, SearchFeedFragment.AllRegisterUserViewHolder.class, Q) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder( SearchFeedFragment.AllRegisterUserViewHolder viewHolder,User model, int position) {


                    viewHolder.setUserName(model.getUsername());
                    viewHolder.setUserProfilePic(Common.stringToBitMap(model.getProfilepicurl()));

                }
            };
            mRecyclerViewSearch.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            return false;
        }
    });


public static class AllRegisterUserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        ImageView mImgProfileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_searchProfilePic);
        TextView mTxtProfileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_searchProfileName);

        public AllRegisterUserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView = mView;
        }

        public void setUserName(String username) {
            mTxtProfileName.setText(username);
        }

        public void setUserProfilePic(Bitmap image) {
            mImgProfileImage.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Implementing Perfect Search with Firebase Realtime Database

[Queries, Part 2: Advanced Searches with Firebase, made Plug-and-Play Simple](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html)

Read this and you will learn why and how about Firebase Realtime Database Search and how to implement a search Query.

## An Alternative solution for your case

you need to update one line of your code.

```
Query Q = mAllUsersDatabaseRef.child("User").orderByChild("username").startAt(newText).endAt(newText+"\uf8ff");
```

this will work for matching from start only. Also you can learn more about [startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt),[endAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt),[equalTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt),[limitToFirst()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt) and [limitToLast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt) they will help you make your search query better without using any external resource other than firebase.

also i hope there is no issues with the [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart).

Comment: hii @Ashutosh thank you for efforts i already try your solution : Query Q = mAllUsersDatabaseRef.child("User").orderByChild("username").startAt(newText).endAt(newText+"\uf8ff"); but thing is that my firebase adapter is not showing while i search.
and link that you provided let me check that i'll get back to you soon. :)

Comment: Hi @RuchaBhatt i assumed your implementation is right and the problem is with the firebase . But one thing is keep bugging me . dont you think reassigning mRecyclerViewSearch.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); adapter again and again is a issue ?