# Swift/Firebase - Query Usernames under random uid that start with UITextField input

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I have looked through every article, stack overflow post, and even the Firebase documentation but still can't find a way to query a user by a UITextField input.**

My database is set up as so:

```
Posts -|
   * Not needed for question *

Users -|
    412bjgaigb-2b41jb4-12j4bj214b -|
          Profile-Url: "https://link-to-image.com"
          Username: "RandomUser"
    3nj2b5io32-b4jk12b412-4124jke -|
          Profile-Url: "https://link-to-image.com"
          Username: "NewPerson"
    h8abgbbuag-n1nj21b1uj-jb41jb5 -|
          Profile-Url: "https://link-to-image.com"
          Username: "RedDawn"
```

In my Firebase Database rules I have it set as:

```
"rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true,
   "Users": {
      "$userid": {
         ".indexOn": ["Username"]
      }
   }
 }
```

In Swift my code is:

```
var strSearch = textfield.text!
ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Username").queryStarting(atValue: strSearch).queryEnding(atValue: "\(strSearch)\\uf8ff").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value)
}
```

The code above is run every time the text field changes but it returns every user under the Users node. The database is large and I don't want my app to fetch all the users in the database.

I only want to fetch the users where the username starts with whatever is in the text field.

**Example:**

A user types in 'R' inside the text field.

The function should only print out "RandomUser" and "RedDawn"

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538034/6738247) to help with only querying strings prefixed with a search string using the `~` character.

Use `.queryStarting(atValue: strSearch).queryEnding(atValue: "\(strSearch)~")`

Also I would change your rules so that the `".indexOn": ["Username"]` is outside of your `$userid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      "Users": {
          ".indexOn": ["Username"],
          "$userid": { }
      }
  }
}
```

### Problem

The only problem seems to be if the usernames you query over are case sensitive. I don't think there is any built in way in Firebase to be case-insensitive while querying. If you need that functionality, I'd suggest storing a second username field with the lowercase version for better queries. There is probably a better approach somewhere else on StackOverflow for this problem.

### Implementation

In case you're currently sending out a query every time the textfield changes, might I suggest using a publisher and debounce() method from the Combine framework. This way you can will only send a query when the user briefly pauses typing. Increasing the interval in the debounce method will have less responsive results, but not as many requests to the database.

I've created a small View Controller you could pop into your test project.

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var field = UITextField()
    
    var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    func setup() {
        
        //MARK: Receive Text Changes from Field
        
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification,
            object: field
        )
        .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] (notification) in
            guard let text = (notification.object as? UITextField)?.text else { return }
            self?.sendQuery(strSearch: text)
        }
        .store(in: &bag)
        
        
        //MARK: UISetup
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(field)
        field.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 250, height: 42)
        field.backgroundColor = .blue
        
    }
    
    func sendQuery(strSearch: String) {
        if strSearch.isEmpty { return }
        
        Database.database().reference().child("Users")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "Username")
            .queryStarting(atValue: strSearch)
            .queryEnding(atValue: "\(strSearch)~")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
        { (snapshot) in
            if let val = snapshot.value {
                print(val)
            }
        }
    }

}
```